# Android Wear : Persistent notification?

Tags: android, notifications, persistent

I can't find anywhere the answer of my question. I would like to create a persistent notification from an Android Wear application that can also update the text displayed on that notification.

I want that notification to display continuously my heartbeat and not be dismissable.

Thank you

Edit :

I have tried this which fully works except that the notification 'flash' a bit every update as if there was a little lag.

```
private void createNotification(int heartRate) {


    if(notificationBuilder == null) {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart_small)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    }

    notificationBuilder.setContentText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_text), heartRate));

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/doubleencore/WearOngoingNotificationSample

Comment: Thank you ! Just tried and the notification kind of flash every update :(